# What database options are available for Nutch 2.1?

Tags: nutch

I'm trying to test out Nutch 2.1 on a single Windows machine. The following command dies:

```
nutch crawl seeds -dir crawl -solr http://somehost:8983/solr -depth 2 -topN 2
```

...with a traceback of several exceptions:

- `java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused`
- `GoraException`
- `SQLTransientConnectionException`
- `org.hsqldb.HsqlException`

This is the same problem as this post: [connection refused error when running Nutch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581492/connection-refused-error-when-running-nutch-2)

It looks like Nutch 2 wants some kind of database already installed, but there's no mention of that in the (sparse) documentation that I can see.

The production environment will eventually be a linux/Hadoop cluster, but for the moment I'm just trying to get a simple local system to work out of the box.

So what options are there for a simple Nutch database? How do you tell Nutch and Gora about the database? HBase might be a good answer as soon as we have our Hadoop cluster up and running. However; in the meantime is there a simple, even slow, database that will work for initial exploration on a single system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried with MYSQL and HBASE.

For MYSQL, this link helps iron out most of the quirks: http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=180

For HBASE, versions above 0.90.x cause problems (Invalid Host Value pair). I've been able to get it working with 0.90.5

Answer (score 3):

The database connection info for Nutch 2.1 is specified in the conf/gora.properties file (should have seen that)